# MySQL Query optimization thru order synchronization of columns and WHERE clause conditions

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Suppose I have a join of four tables, Table 1 which is referencing the other 3 tables (Table2,3,4) via foreign key relations:

```
SELECT a.column_a, b.column_b, c.column_c, d.column_d
FROM Table1 a, Table2 b, Table3 c, Table4 d
WHERE a.col1_fk=d.col_id
AND a.col2_fk=c.col_id
AND a.col3_fk=b.col_id
```

In order to have the best optimization of the above statement, should the join conditions be in the same order in which the columns of the SELECT statement are ? Hence, is my example above least optimized ? Or is the said order of no importance ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's of no importance. The query optimizer decides, which table is read first.
This might also change when your data size is growing. For example, one day your `WHERE` clause filters 90% of a table, so MySQL decides to read this table first. A thousand `INSERT`s later, the same `WHERE` clause might filter just 1%. Then MySQL may decide to read it last, or even do a full table scan.

Don't worry about this kind of optimization. If you want to optimize, read about [`EXPLAIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html) (which also shows you in which order the tables are read, aside from if and which indexes are used) and [learn to use indexes](http://use-the-index-luke.com) properly.

And, no offense, what you should really learn is the proper join syntax that was introduced with the ANSI SQL Standard from 1992. [Here](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) are some examples.

Comment: No offense taken - I know what you mean: INNER JOIN, OUTER JOIN etc. Maybe one day I will. I've been using SQL since 1993 - in and out. The old way still works well for my joins. The new way seems only to do the same thing in a more complicated way.

Comment: About indexes, I know that all fields which participate in a WHERE clause should be indexed. These being primary and foreign keys, they are. I know about EXPLAIN (EXPLAIN PLAN), but I have never used it - curiously enough. I will read about it.